# How to avoid electromagnetic interference on ESP32 input

Tags: esp8266, interrupt, input, esp32

I've realized a simple circuit like the following, in order to implement a rain gauge that I can access via HTTP:

[image]

[image]

With the following sketch:

```
#include <WebServer.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>

/**
 * This constant is calculated with the following procedure:
 * - Area of pluviometer is 55 cm^2
 * - Volume of test water is 100 cm^2
 * Resulting height of water is 1.82 cm. Using this water quantity, generates 40 ticks of the pluviometer. So every tick is 0.455 mm of rain.
 */
const double millimetersPerTick = 0.455;
const char* ssid = "*********";
const char* password = "*********";

WebServer server(80);

/* LED pin */
byte ledPin = 2;
/* pin that is attached to interrupt */
byte interruptPin = 14;
/* hold the state of LED when toggling */
volatile byte state = LOW;
volatile int interruptCounter = 0;
int numberOfInterrupts = 0;
portMUX_TYPE mux = portMUX_INITIALIZER_UNLOCKED;

void IRAM_ATTR handleInterrupt() {
  portENTER_CRITICAL_ISR(&mux);
  interruptCounter++;
  portEXIT_CRITICAL_ISR(&mux);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // WIFI initialization
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);  

  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  /* set the interrupt pin as input pullup*/
  pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  /* attach interrupt to the pin
  function blink will be invoked when interrupt occurs
  interrupt occurs whenever the pin change value */

   // Notify wifi connection
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);    
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);    

  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), handleInterrupt, RISING);

  server.on("/", []() {
    server.send(200, "text/plain", String(millimetersPerTick * numberOfInterrupts));
    numberOfInterrupts = 0;
  });

  server.onNotFound([]() {
    server.send(404, "text/plain", "Not found");
  });

  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  server.handleClient();

  if(interruptCounter>0) {
    portENTER_CRITICAL(&mux);
    interruptCounter--;
    portEXIT_CRITICAL(&mux);

    numberOfInterrupts++;
    Serial.print("An interrupt has occurred. Total: ");
    Serial.println(numberOfInterrupts);
    state = !state;
    digitalWrite(ledPin, state);    
    delay(100);
    state = !state;
    digitalWrite(ledPin, state);    
  }  
}
```

The main issue of this circuit is that if I connect the AC plug it suffers from interferences from the household electricity. For example if I turn on the light, the interrupt is called. I tried also to buy an EMI filter like [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1PCS-LOT-EMI-Filter-CW1B-10A-L-10A-115V-250V-CW1B-50-60Hz/32852691198.html) but it doesn't reduce the problem. What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: I think it is moment you should try another interrupt pin(s).

Comment: I have to check better, but it seems that other have this issue with reed switches that in some configuration act like antennas and receive interferences (see [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=485107.0) and [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=485107.0)).

Comment: i would try two cheap/simple fixes: 1. a ferrite bead or two on the ac input and the dc output. 2. a smoothing capacitor across the vout of your hilink (100-2200u).

Comment: I tried with a battery pack and it happens. I suspect the problem is the long wire for reed switch that is working like an antenna.

Answer (score 1):

I researched the power supply shown in your photo and found this comment:
[image: from randomnerdtutorials]

[esp8266 hilink](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-hi-link-hlk-pm03/)